# Tomcat passing mutiple base ports as environment variables

Tags: tomcat

How to pass multiple connector ports through command line as environment variables to tomcat 7.0.55
I have used as below.

```
<Server port="${CATALINA_SHUT_PORT}" shutdown="7005"><Service name="Catalina">

 <Connector port="${CATALINA_BASE_PORT}" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                maxThreads="500" minSpareThreads="150" maxSpareThreads="200"
                enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="200"
                connectionTimeout="300000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
                strategy="ms" socketBuffer="20480"/>

 <Connector port="${CATALINA_SECOND_BASE_PORT}" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="100" maxSpareThreads="150"
                enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="200"
                connectionTimeout="-1" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" strategy="ms" socketBuffer="20480"/>
```

When i passed, the values through environment variables, the server process is up and listening on the specified ports. However it is giving error at shutdown time. Tomcat is failed to shutdown.

It is giving error as failed to shutdown. The shutdown script is connecting to 8005 default shutdown port.

Sriram.

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass the same environment variables to shutdown script. Otherwise tomcat unable to find the shutdown port and try connecting default port of 8005.

Sriram.